# Cannot find bounds of current function (Code::Blocks) C++

Tags: c++, runtime-error, codeblocks

I am using the latest version of Code::Blocks. I have a function that passes in a string and a vector. The function compiles with no errors. However, when I run the debugger, it immediately leads me to line 118 (which I have noted) and gives me trouble. The error that comes up says "Cannot find bounds of current function".

Here is the function, which takes in a line of code of a variable declaration (like "var c=0"), and gets the variable of it and adds its value to the vector, v, a struct with an `int value` and `string name`:

```
char get_variable_declaration(string line, vector<variable> &v)
{
    string b;
    variable t;
    char d[0];
    int counter = 0;
    int a;
    for (int i = 0; i<line.size(); i++) {
        if (line[i] == 'r' && counter != 1) {
           b[0] = line [i+2];
           counter ++;
        }
        if (line[i] == '=') {
            b[1]=line[i+1];
        }
    }
    t.name = b[0];
    d[0] = b[1];
    a = atoi (d);
    t.value = a;
    v.push_back (t);
    return b[0];

    //This function will take in a line of code
    //that is confirmed to have a variable declaration
    //it will add the variable to the list of
    //vectors
}
```

Here is when it is called:

```
bool read_code(string file_name, vector<funct> &my_functions, vector<variable> & v)
{
    vector<string> code;
    string s;
    std::size_t found;
    bool flag;
    funct new_function;

    ifstream in;
    in.open(file_name.c_str());
    if(in.is_open())
    {
        //read in file line by line and put it into a vector called code
        while(in.peek()!=EOF)
        {
            getline(in,s);
            code.push_back(s);
        }
        in.clear();
        in.close();

        //read through each line of the code, determine if it's a variable or function (definition or call)
        //here it makes reference to functions (listed following this one) which will actually decompose the line
        //for information
        for(int i=0;i<code.size();i++)
        {
            //check if it's a variable declaration
            found = code[i].find("var");
            if(found!=std::string::npos)    //its a variable declaration
                get_variable_declaration(code[i], v); //ERROR CANNOT FIND..

            //check if it's a function. it'll go in the list of functions
            found = code[i].find("funct");
            if (found!=std::string::npos)   //that means it's a function
            {
                new_function.funct_name=get_function_name(code[i]);
                new_function.commands.clear();
                i+=2;   //skip over the open curly brace
                flag=false;
                while(!flag)
                {
                    found = code[i].find("}");
                    if(found==std::string::npos)
                    {
                        new_function.commands.push_back(code[i]);
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        my_functions.push_back(new_function);
                        flag=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot locate this file" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: Yes, this is a homework assignment. No, I am not looking for anyone to finish this assignment for me. But, I am still mostly a novice at coding, in need of some assistance, so I ask if you know what is going on, please help me address this issue. Thanks!

Edit: I have gotten this to work on another compiler w/o the text file I am reading from. Not sure if this is a universal issue, or one that the other compiler just didn't pick up on.

Comment: `char d[0];` seems wrong

Comment: @AntonSavin to use the atoi function, you need to have a constant character value. I think that is what it is referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. To correctly use atoi, you cannot use a specific character from a string or character array. If you declare a `char a[3]`, and you want to use atoi, you must use it like `int value = atoi(a)` and not `value = atoi(a[2])`. If you do not do it this way, it will cause a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems with this section of code:

```
string b;

for (int i = 0; i<line.size(); i++) {
    if (line[i] == 'r' && counter != 1) {
       b[0] = line [i+2];
       counter ++;
    }
    if (line[i] == '=') {
        b[1]=line[i+1];
    }
}
```

Problems:

- If the last character in `line` is 'r', undefined behavior can occur.
- If the next to last character in `line` is 'r', undefined behavior can occur.
- If the last character in `line` is '=', undefined behavior occurs.
- Both assignments to `b[0]` and `b[1]` is undefined behavior. The `b` string is empty.

There are also other instances of undefined behavior that have been noted in the comments, which I won't duplicate.

Comment: Is there an issue with the declaration of d[0]? How would I use the atoi() function without declaring it as such?

Comment: d[0] declares an array whose size is zero, it contains zero elements. And then you attempt to initialize this array, that has zero elements. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Ah, yes it does. Thank you.